# JPA/Hibernate ManyToMany not nullable contstraint

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a parent entity that has a Many-to-Many relation with its children. However I have a constraint that a Parent must at least have 1 Child. How can we describe this with JPA/Hibernate annotations?

```
@Entity
public class Parent {
    //parent must have at least 1 Child
    @ManyToMany
    private Set<Child> children    
}
```

At the moment I'm thinking of just using interceptors as follows:

```
@PrePersist
@PreUpdate
private validate() {
    if(children.size() < 1) 
      throw new PersistenceException()
}
```

Or possibly handle this at service layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the Hibernate Validator, that uses JSR 303 and is interpreted as database validation also.
Therefore you can use the @NotEmpty annotation for validation like this:

```
 @ManyToMany
 @NotEmpty
    private Set<Child> children
```